# Query the Author column using login "domain\user"

Tags: caml-query, caml

I need to query a SharePoint list and specifically the Author column with a given login in the form "domain\username".

I read that I must switch the column's "Show Field" property to "Account", but unfortunately that would be too disruptive for our users, who are used to the friendly name.

In addition to that, I don't have the user SharePoint ID, just the login. Did I run out of options? Many thanks.

Comment: Does this need to be for the current logged in user or are you trying to pass a specific user?

Comment: I am trying to pass a specific user, coming from our database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen domain\username be used reliably to directly query the list. What I have done though, is use the [GetUserInfo web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774637.aspx) to get the user id, and then pass that through to my CAML in another function.

Pseudo code:

```
    function getListItemsForUser(userid){
    var caml = "<Where>"+
          "<Eq>"+
             "<FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True' />"+
             "<Value Type='Integer'>" + userid + "</Value>"+
          "</Eq>"+
       "</Where>";
//rest of your logic
    }
```

I don't have any of the instances where I've used it handy.